# Issue connecting Express.js API in Elastic Beanstalk to MongoDB Atlas during autoscaling

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mongodb-atlas, exp

[image]

I'm currently facing an issue with connecting my Express.js API, which is running in an Elastic Beanstalk environment, to my MongoDB Atlas database. My concern is that when autoscaling is triggered, the new instances' IP addresses are not automatically registered in the access network configuration in Atlas. As a result, every incoming request is being rejected by Atlas.

I've already set up my Express.js API on Elastic Beanstalk, and it's working fine with the existing instance. However, I'm unsure how to handle the autoscaling scenario.

I would appreciate any guidance or best practices to ensure a proper connection between my Express.js API and MongoDB Atlas, even when autoscaling is triggered. Specifically, I need a solution that automatically updates the access network configuration in Atlas with the new instances' IP addresses.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score -1):

Use DNS-based Connection: Instead of relying on IP addresses for the connection, consider using DNS-based connection string that allows you to connect to the database using a domain name rather than specific IP addresses.

Whitelist CIDR Block Range: In your MongoDB Atlas dashboard, configure the access network settings to allow incoming connections from a CIDR block range that covers the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Elastic Beanstalk Environment Variables: Store the MongoDB connection string or any other sensitive configuration information as environment variables within your Elastic Beanstalk environment. This approach helps maintain separation between your application code and configuration details. You can access these environment variables within your Express.js API code to establish the connection to MongoDB Atlas.

Elastic Beanstalk Configuration Updates: Configure your Elastic Beanstalk environment to automatically update the MongoDB connection string or relevant environment variables when autoscaling is triggered. You can leverage Elastic Beanstalk hooks or event-driven mechanisms to handle these updates.

Database Connection Pooling: Implement connection pooling within your Express.js API to efficiently manage database connections. Connection pooling allows multiple requests to reuse and share database connections, reducing the overhead of establishing a new connection for each request. This helps improve performance and resource utilization, especially in autoscaling scenarios where multiple instances are involved.